# Will Catalina users be able to stubbornly cling to iTunes?

Tags: itunes, catalina

[iTunes won't be bundled with Catalina](https://www.apple.com/itunes/).  A user of the beta has [identified some serious deficiencies](https://djtechtools.com/2019/06/03/itunes-discontinued-in-new-macos-catalina-less-bloated-apple-music-app-to-replace-it/) in the replacement.  I don’t argue with the consensus that iTunes is a mess, but some of the disappearing features are valuable.

The “announcement” (aka “marketing”) says that iTunes 12.8 can be used with “OS X version 10.10.5 or later” which technically implies it will continue to be usable.  But I’m skeptical.

Answer (score 1):

The page you've linked specially states that 12.8 is available for "previous versions of macOS". I think it is clear that iTunes on Catalina is not an intended configuration, nor is it probably officially supported by Apple.

Indeed if you try to install iTunes 12 on the Catalina GM, you'll be informed that it is incompatible software - and won't install.

If you really, really want to run iTunes on Catalina, you can use this [script](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/itunes-12-6-5-3-on-macos-catalina-10-15.2184518/post-27807492) to allow installation.

Comment: What is used in place of iTunes?

Comment: Apple Music, Apple Podcast and Apple TV. That is the names of the new apps.

Comment: It says we can "always download" it for those versions, which implies users of those versions won't lose access to it.  But it also says "10.10.5 or later” without saying "except for 10.14 and later."   But if it is already installed, will it run?  That page links to another that suggests Catalina might remove "iTunesAccess" which I see is one of the things that script installs.  They also talk about a "patched version" of iTunes with version number 13.6.5.3—much higher than the 12.9.5.5 current in Mojave.

Comment: I know what it says - and I’ve explained what I think it means. If it is already installed, it will be upgraded to the new apps. And yes, the patched version is what I linked... essentially the 13 number is fake for the purpose of circumventing the “incompatible” prompt.